# Calling @async method inside synchronzied block in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, concurrency

I am having a service method which performs DB save based on status and sends mail asynchronously. Since it is accessed concurrently I am making the block synchronized.

code:

```
     synchronized(this){
           status = dao.getStatus(id);
           if(status != request.getStatus()) {
              dao.save(obj);
              process.sendMail();
           }
      }


 class Process {  
    @Async
    public void sendMail() {}
}
```

Does this going to affect the background mail operation? whether the waiting thread will wait for the mail operation to finish?

Comment: Is the sendMail method in the same class as the method with the synchronized block?

Comment: No. It is in another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your method

```
@Async
public void sendMail() {}
```

is in same class then it won't work.

For `@Async`

1. it must be applied to public methods only
2. self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same
   class – won’t work

So, I think your method `sendMail` will work fine as long as it is in a different class then the `synchronized` block.

Comment: whether the waiting thread will wait for the mail operation to finish?